# Ruby On Rails adding new page after scaffolding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I made a scaffold named b_page and I created a migration for bio I added a biopage.html.erb
In controller:

```
def biopage
@b_pages = BPage.all
end
```

in routes.rb

```
resources :b_pages do  
collection do  
  get 'biopage'  
 end 
end
```

in bio.html.erb:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<h1>Bio of :</h1>
<h2><b><%= @b_page.Bpage_name %></b></h2>
<h3><%= @b_page.user.email %></h3>
</div>
<%= @b_page.bio %>
```

but i still get the error:

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BPagesController#show
Couldn't find BPage with 'id'=biopage
highlighting:

```
      @b_page = BPage.find(params[:id])
```

Comment: You have @b_pages in your controller and are trying to access @biopage in views. Moreso, if you use `all` you have to loop through it. Please, make the question clearer.

Comment: you're binding `@b_page` using an id key in your params, but you didn't set your route to look for an in the url. Try changing that to `get 'biopage:id'`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this seems a bit odd to me:

```
resources :b_pages do  
  collection do  
    get 'biopage'  
  end 
end
```

as it will result in a route like: `/b_pages/biopage`. You might want to just do something like:

```
resources :b_pages, except: :show
get '/biopage/:id', to: 'b_pages#show'
```

This way, your `biopage` route will go to the `show` controller method and you will still have the other `b_pages` routes to work with.

You are seeing the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` error message because you have no `BPage` object to show, so the `show` method is complaining. Notice how the route I wrote above uses `:id` - this is because the `show` action normally takes an id of some record to display on the front end. If you want to use `biopage` and link it to the `show` method, you should be returning an object to actually show. Otherwise you should probably create a completely different controller method for `biopage` that does not interfere with the `b_pages` resources. Something like this in the routes:

```
resources :b_pages
get '/biopage/:id', to: 'b_pages#your_method'
```

and in the controller you'd have

```
class BPages < ApplicationController
  # index, show, destroy, etc. here

  def your_method
    # Get whatever object you want returned here
  end
end
```